# CDocument::SetPathName(..) crash in VS2015

Tags: mfc

I upgrade an App from VS2008 to VS2015.

I get an Exception, which I assume is triggered from

```
/*virtual*/ BOOL CMyAppDoc::SaveModified()
{
  if (!IsModified())
    return TRUE;        // nothing to do

  CString str = GetPathName();
  SetPathName(str, TRUE);   // assign a PathName and add to MRU !
  return OnSaveDocument(str);           

}
```

The ErrorBox shows: "Encountered an inproper argument".

Comment: Step through the debugger and tell us what functions causes the exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated further, the error comes from

```
void CRecentFileList::Add(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, LPCTSTR lpszAppID)
{
  ..
  hr = _AfxSHCreateItemFromParsingName(lpWPath, NULL, IID_IShellItem,LPVOID*)&psi);
  ENSURE(SUCCEEDED(hr));
  ..

}
```

hr Errorcode is 2, which means ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND : The system cannot find the file specified.

The workaround is first save the file with OnSaveDocument(..), then call SetPathName(..)